# How to deal with build dependencies in source RPM?

Tags: qt, package, fedora, rpm, yum

I don't usually use Fedora or RPMs, so I'm flying blind here. There are lots of similar questions around here, but none that I found are to the exact point where I'm stuck.

I have the source RPM for an old game program on Fedora ("six" is the game). I want to add a couple of features, but first I want to make sure I know how to compile it so that any future problems are new. I have not made any changes yet at all.

I'm not completely helpless -- when I did

```
rpmbuild --recompile six-*.src.rpm
```

I got a complaint about a missing dependency: "kdelibs3-devel", but

```
dnf install kdelibs3-devel
```

took care of that.

However, now the complaints are more nuanced.  When I retried rpmbuild, it ended with

```
checking crt_externs.h usability... no
checking crt_externs.h presence... no
checking for crt_externs.h... no
checking for _NSGetEnviron... no
checking for vsnprintf... yes
checking for snprintf... yes
checking for X... libraries /usr/lib64, headers .
checking for IceConnectionNumber in -lICE... yes
checking for libXext... yes
checking for pthread_create in -lpthread... yes
checking for extra includes... no
checking for extra libs... no
checking for libz... -lz
checking for libpng... -lpng -lz -lm
checking for libjpeg6b... no
checking for libjpeg... no
configure: WARNING: libjpeg not found. disable JPEG support.
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for Qt... configure: error: Qt (>= Qt 3.3 and < 4.0) (library qt-mt) not found. Please check your installation!
For more details about this problem, look at the end of config.log.
Make sure that you have compiled Qt with thread support!
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.y8dvN5 (%build)  

RPM build errors:
    user mockbuild does not exist - using root
    user mockbuild does not exist - using root
    user mockbuild does not exist - using root
    user mockbuild does not exist - using root
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.y8dvN5 (%build)
```

Several things here seem odd, but the obvious biggie is the failure to find Qt between 3.3 and 4.0.  This obviously compiled for the Fedora maintainers, so the right thing should be available, but I have no idea what its exact name would be, or how to find it and make it available.

Help, please.
.

Comment: I would also note that the system DOES have an installed libjpeg-turbo.  I wonder if a libjpeg is available (dnf does not seem to think so).

Comment: FYI, if you'd rather struggle with the original source, the [Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20100707025448/http://six.retes.hu/download/) still has them.  Strangely, when I downloaded a `*.tar.gz` file, it was actually just a `*.tar` file.

Comment: The original source will not build with modern gcc compiler; you need the patches Fedora added.

Comment: Hence, *the struggle*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing to do here is use higher-level tools. Specifically, use [mock](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/mock/). This is a tool which:

- manages a build environment (either a chroot or container-based),
  so you don't have to worry about that,
- handles things like the build dependencies, so you don't have to worry about that, and
- makes sure that your build is "clean" rather than influenced by your own user environment so you don't have to worry about that.

In short: `mock --rebuild six-*.src.rpm`

Comment: Higher level tools involve an additinal learning curve.  I'm pretty sure I'll never do this again, so I'm hoping a simpler answer emerges.  I'm not interested even in Fedora per se, just in getting six patched and running.  I'll probably be able to migrate a non-gui version to Ubuntu.

Comment: I don't think that generalization really is true. Many higher-level tools are wrappers which simplify things and reduce manual work. That is very much the case here.

Comment: You're kidding yourself.  Your description already included two things I've either never used or mostly forgotten: containers and chroot.  Presumably they are just the first drops for this bucket.  I'd expect more, include mock itself.  Granted, once it was working I'd expect it to be pretty smooth, but there will be no sequel for me to enjoy that in.

Comment: You're going to need to know those things eventually in order to package software effectively for any operating system. But with this tool, you'll have to _know them less_. I have edited my answer to clarify.

Comment: WOW!  that command did a whole bunch of stuff, and it sure looks like it built 32- and 64-bit RPMs.  A bunch of warnings (from gcc I think), and some tests, etc., but no fatal errors.  Answer accepted.  Thanks.

Comment: Now I just have to understand how to modify the source rpm and run mock against the modified version.  That's a learning curve I cannot avoid, of course.

Comment: And I was right about the learning curve.  I can build the RPMS it seems (though I haven't tested them yet) but I cannot figure out if mock made a new SRPM, and if not how to make it do so.  What I really want is a sequence of commands, and names of directories involved, to download SRPM, unpack it, patch it, remake a new SRPM, rebuild binary RPM(s), install those binaries (possibly on top of stuff from the repos), prepare a pull request and/or patch and submit it.  Composing a new question now.

Answer (score 2):

If you see errors about a specific library missing, you can use `dnf` itself to find out the name. For example, on Fedora 35:

```
$ sudo dnf repoquery --whatprovides '*qt-mt*'
qt3-0:3.3.8b-88.fc35.i686
qt3-0:3.3.8b-88.fc35.x86_64
qt3-devel-0:3.3.8b-88.fc35.i686
qt3-devel-0:3.3.8b-88.fc35.x86_64
```

I guess you just need to `dnf install qt3-devel`.

As for libjpeg, do you have `libjpeg-turbo-devel` installed? Configure programs generally look for the `-devel` stuff rather than just the library (`libjpeg`). If you have it installed and it's still not picked up, maybe the software is just not compatible with `libjpeg-turbo`. Fixing that would be a separate challenge.

Comment: And to see what a package requires you can use `dnf repoquery --requires ...`.

Comment: A little bit of progress: indeed installing libjped-turbo-devel made the rebuild a little cleaner.  But dnf insists that both qt-3.3 and qt-3.3-devel are already installed.  And a rebuild continues to fail with the same final message.

Comment: So I'm wondering if asking for qt3 was specific enough. The messages from dnf included: Package qt3-devel-3.3.8b-88.fc35.x86_64 is already installed   and   Package qt3-3.3.8b-88.fc35.x86_64 is already installed.  Should I have asked for something else?  They look a lot like what you found when asking for qt-mt but not quite identical.

Answer (score 0):

Using mock got me the ability to build the package, but I could not figure out how to do further work on it because the chroot left behind by mock did not seem functional.  So I asked this question in a different way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70911242), and got a really good answer (the second one).