# How to modify a Fedora package and fix bugs

Tags: debugging, fedora, rpm, pull-request

I have an old old game from Fedora, in a package named six.  It has a bug and I want to add a couple of simple features.  I asked here about one part of the process, (see [How to deal with build dependencies in source RPM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70871162) ) got some answers, and find that the learning curve is just too much for my old brain.  Documentation tends to want to cover everything a package can do and it's hard for me to pick out the pieces I need.

What I am really hoping for is a complete workflow (hopefully just a list of commands and a mention of the directories involved).

It would start with this (it works and may even be standard):

- Find the SRPM with rpm -qi six | grep Source
- Fetch with rpm -i six-0.5.3-38.fc35.src.rpm

result: sources and spec files in ~/rpmbuild

What I need filled in are the following steps after I modify and test the new version:

- build new SRPM (can mock do this?)
- build new RPMs and install them locally (I will test and repeat as needed)
- report bug and fixes, possibly as a pull request

The steps may be reorganized if needed.  I know mock can build RPMs from a SRPM, but I did not see how to go direct from sources to installation, and building fails outside of mock (some problem with qt-mt).

I'm hoping for a list of commands that will work together to do these things.  I've done what I could short of spending a week understanding the terminology mismatches between the various man pages.  Or just odd usages (why does a REbuild of a SRPM build binary RPMS but not an SRPM?)

BTW if you want to see the bug I mentioned,

- install six
- start it
- set Black to human
- set White to expert
- set Swap enabled
- click on any hex in the top (or bottom) row and watch six report a crash and quit.

You can try again, clicking in the middle of the board and notice it does not crash.

I'm not all that surprised the bug hasn't been noticed before.  Swap is usually only enabled between experienced players.  I doubt an experienced player would make the first move in the top or bottom row against another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had fun getting auto-player to build today. My work on SentryPeer has paid off! :-)

How to explain! I needed to patch some code and autoconf/automake links. Here goes:

Get the src rpm:

```
sudo dnf download --source six -y
```

Install rpm-build:

```
sudo dnf install rpm-build
mkdir -p ~/rpmbuild/{BUILD,RPMS,SOURCES,SPECS,SRPMS}
```

Install the src rpm (it will be in the directory you ran step 1.):

```
rpm -ivh six-0.5.3-38.fc35.src.rpm
```

Install the build requirements as per https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/six/blob/rawhide/f/six.spec e.g. it needs:

```
BuildRequires: make
BuildRequires:  gcc
BuildRequires:  kdelibs3-devel
BuildRequires:  desktop-file-utils
```

so do:

```
sudo dnf install make gcc kdelibs3-devel desktop-file-utils
```

run the rpmbuild command so it applies all the patches etc. as the src rpm comes with six-0.5.3.tar.gz (which is not the same as the code on github at - https://github.com/melisgl/six which I could not get compiled):

These files I mean:

```
localhost ~/rpmbuild/BUILD/six-0.5.3/tests $ ls ../../../SOURCES/
six-gcc43.patch
six-0.5.3.tar.gz
six-fix-DSO.patch
```

Run:

```
rpmbuild -ba ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/six.spec
```

rpms should be built, but auto-player is an extra program not built by default, as you know.

This creates a BUILD folder.

```
cd ~/rpmbuild/BUILD/six-0.5.3/tests
```

edit Makefile.am line 84 and add this to the bit after $(LIB_KFILE):

```
-lqt-mt
```

so it looks like:

```
-lm $(LIB_KFILE) -lqt-mt
```

and do the same on line 374 of Makefile.in

By default it wasn't linking to libqt-mt

Go into top level and run configure again to re-generate the Makefile:

```
cd ~/rpmbuild/BUILD/six-0.5.3
./configure
make clean
make
make check
```

These should all be good

Go back into tests folder:

```
cd ~/rpmbuild/BUILD/six-0.5.3/tests
```

Open auto-player.cpp and add this at line 6 (was missing this, so not sure how it ever compiled):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

save the file.

Build the program:

```
make auto-player
```

Run it:

```
./auto-player filename player1 player2
```

as per the code is runs like:

```
void play(char *filename, Poi<HexPlayer> vert, Poi<HexPlayer> hori)
```

Let me know how you get on!

Thanks!

--
https://sentrypeer.org

Comment: GENIUS!! THANK YOU SO MUCH. It worked perfectly, right away.   I did also create the mockbuild user, just to shut up a warning in the build process.  And I was able to test the auto-player with the command  'auto-player start-positions/a2.six expert expert'  inside the test directory

Answer (score 4):

You handle it very well. You are actually missing only one thing. After you install the src.rpm with:

rpm -i six-0.5.3-38.fc35.src.rpm

You have `six.spec` in `~/rpmbuild/SPECS`
and `six-SOMETHING.tar.gz` in `~/rpmbuild/SOURCES`

The quick and dirty way is to unpack that `six-SOMETHING.tar.gz`. Modify the the file and pack it back. Into the same structure as had the original tar ball.

And then just:

rpmbuild -bs ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/six.spec

this will produce the src.rpm and you can then build it using mock:

mock six.src.rpm

(an even quicker and dirtier way is to call `rpmbuild -ba` which builds the rpm directly, but mock is a cleaner way).

The standard way of handling fixes in packages is to add a patch. https://rpm-packaging-guide.github.io/#patching-software But if you do not care about sustainability and long-term security, then the path above is just fine.

If you want to file a bug against fedora six's package you can do it here  https://bugz.fedoraproject.org/six

Comment: Thank you.  I will test all  this, but I have accepted the answer.

Comment: Two minor tweaks for anyone as new to this as I am:  it should read "this will produce six-SOMETHING.src.rpm" and "mock PATH/six-SOMETHING.src.rpm"; with those tweaks it seems to work fine.