# How to open up a Fedora package to work on it

Tags: makefile, fedora, rpm, chroot

I asked a question and got a sketch of how to open and patch a Fedora package.  See [How to modify a Fedora package and fix bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70911242)

What was missing was how to work on the package.  I cannot build it outside of the chroot, apparently because of a problem with Qt (The package uses Qt3).  I need to know how to get into the details of makes and tests because I want software that is actually part of the SRPM, but does not make it into the distributed RPM -- it is only used to test the package during building.

So how do I find the chroot, get into it, mess around, and build some of the messed-around bits, fix what I just broke and try again, and maybe use the final result outside the chroot?  Or maybe there's a completely different way.

None of the docs I've seen get into these dirty little bits.  And it is complicated by my inability to do a build outside the chroot.

In the end, I'll probably construct an SRPM (for my own use) that just makes the test program (a command-line version of the graphic program that the original package is all about).  But I'll need to work on it quite a bit before that's ready to go.

Probably it's good enough if someone can show me how and where to get into the chroot and do commands like 'make', then use the results outside the chroot.

Comment: This is very general question (or rather comment) which can be hardly satisfied by short answer.

Comment: I expect it can.  Since I can run mock to build the thing, I should have everything necessary.  I can see auto-player in the results, but when I try to run it, it says file not found.  But the file is there, "file" says it's an ELF.  It doesn't help if I chroot in there as root.  I can't seem to get to be user mockbuild.  So I suspect a combination of su, chroot and maybe a few others would at least get me to where i could type ./autoplayer and have it play.  Anything to get it to be in the binary result would also be fine.  I just want to get to that program and run it, however it is done.